# MSAL access token getting unauthorized with MicrosoftIdentityWebApi Authentication

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I set up my Startup Class below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

My AzureAd appsettings.json is below:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "2f0d9252-e207-4d7f-b4da-*******",
    "TenantId": "de1ef02c-7cfa-46b8-a02b-*******",
    "Audience": "2f0d9252-e207-4d7f-b4da-*******"
  }
```

Now my controller below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        //To be put on appsettings.json
        string clientId = "2f0d9252-e207-4d7f-b4da-0cc618e77c93";
        string tenantId = "de1ef02c-7cfa-46b8-a02b-61ab78bc602b";

        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:5000")
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { };

        //Azure Login Success here
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        //Azure service graph get success.
        string graphResult = await "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me"
            .WithOAuthBearerToken(result.AccessToken)
            .GetStringAsync();

        //I pass the AccessToken from the result. But I'm getting UnAuthorized.
        string authorizeResult = await "https://localhost:44328/weatherforecast/AuthorizeGet"
            .WithOAuthBearerToken(result.AccessToken)
            .GetStringAsync();

        return graphResult;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> AuthorizeGet()
    {
        return "Authorize";
    }
```

The Azure Login will success here. But after I get the token and request to AuthorizeGet Api. It will give me Unauthorized 401.

Anything I missed out for the configuration?

Below is my Directory Authentication config.

[image]

Comment: You’re missing scopes for which you want to acquire token. Also, please share the code instead of screenshots.

Comment: @GauravMantri what should I put on the scope? Sorry Im new to this.

Comment: I have updated my description to a code instead of screenshots. Please help

Comment: Typically your scope would be `api://{your-application-client-id}`. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration.

Comment: So your code would be something like `string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://2f0d9252-e207-4d7f-b4da-*******" };`

Comment: Okay I will try.

Comment: I still get this error, even I added the scopes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238835/discussion-between-anthony-earl-r-cuartero-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: Anyway, I have solved it by adding Scopes in Azure AD and adding it on my MSAL. Thanks man

Comment: @AnthonyEarlR.Cuartero how did you solve this, can you please explain in detail?